# Result of $var ($unread) cause text to change color

Tags: php

I've got a message system that is set up in a jquery mobile site and is linked to by list items as a menu. In the `<li>` set up as a link to the message section is the message unread count.

```
<li>
 <a href='.../employee/msgsys/display_messages.php' target="_self">
    Messages (<?php echo ($unread);?>)
  </a>
</li>
```

What I would like to do is cause the text of messages and count ($unread) to turn red when there is at least 1 new unread message. I've searched on here to find something but nothing I found worked. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Use AJAX and call it on time intervals? Jquery let us call function's on specific time intervals.

Comment: Are you asking about automation (auto checking to see if there are new messages) or are you literally unsure how to turn the color of the message red when there is an unread message (css)?

Comment: @Rasclatt, I'm trying to turn the color of the message red when there is an unread message. I've got it checking just fine and it changes the numerical value when there is an unread message to the right number, i just for the life of me get the color to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very plainly and without going into the AJAX calls, this seems to be what you need.

```
<li>
  <a href='...' target="_self" class="<?php echo count($unread)>0 ? "youve-got-mail" : ""; ?>">
    Messages (<?php echo ($unread); ?>)
  </a>
</li>


.youve-got-mail{
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't change the color at all. There must be something missing in the code I've written before but i'm not sure what.

Comment: You probably have it styled somewhere else in CSS that [has a higher specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) than this declaration. If you can't find it, you can change this to `.parent-element .parent li a span` (or otherwise make it more specific) or `red !important;`.

Comment: I tried the    red !important; and it just turns the line red if there are 0 or >1 I've been searching my css but haven't found anything

Comment: Ok ended up that this did seem to work, just had to make a couple changes. ended up with this:
 `<li> 
<a href='…; target="_self" class="<?php echo count($unread)<1 ? "no-mail" : "youve-got-mail"; ?>">
 Messages (<?php echo ($unread); ?>) 

}
 .youve-got-mail{ 
color: red !important; 
}
 .no-mail{
 color: green !important;
 }`

So thank you so much!